# Running shell script using PHP over http

Tags: apache2, php, scripts, git

OS - Ubuntu 14.04
Well I am working on deployment using GIT webhooks for it.
I havea added the deployment keys to git repo and now I want to trigger the `git pull origin master command` when a push happens from my local repo.
This is the test.php file I call via browser.

```
<?php       
    //echo "THis is a test file on a test repo for testing the deploy functionality using github webhooks!!!!";
    echo exec('whoami');
    echo exec('sh -x /var/www/iq/deploy-test/git.sh');
?>
```

the shell file

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/proj-dir/deploy-test
git pull origin master
```

When I run this on terminal using

`php test.php` I get the correct result as expected

```
 ubuntu From github.com:repo/test
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 Already up-to-date.
```

ubuntu for `whoami` and the git pull output.

Now heres the issue when I call the same `http://example.com/test.php` on browser it shows the user or `whoami` output as `www-data`,which is apache user,but I tried updating the permissions of the php file to execute and changing the user to `www-data` but did not work.
**What updates do I need to make so the file works via browser request?**

If I need to update the sudoers file what should be the updates?

Comment: how can I fix it? apache. conf?

Comment: if calls for exec were blocked then `whoami` should not work right? @muru

Comment: hmm, yes. Do the Apache logs indicate anything?

Comment: `Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
+ cd /var/www/proj/deploy-test
+ git pull origin master
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.` But when I run it via terminal(`php test.php`) it works fine.

Comment: "Host key verification failed" - if you're using Git over SSH, the web server a) won't have the Git server in it's `known_hosts`, and b) won't have access to your private key for authentication.

Comment: ok so I need to add git to known hosts,but i believe git does that when we generate the ssh keys.Correct me. If not how to add them to the known hosts

Comment: The problem is, when run by the web server, the home directory and SSH settings are for the user the webserver runs as (`www-data`), *not* your user.

Comment: yes,i read through a few posts and learnt that we need to update the sudoers file to add `www-data` in it with permissions to run script.But I have no knowledge how to edit it.If you can update how i must add the entry to visudo file

Comment: `www-data` does not have a user folder as its the apache user,right? so how can we have the ssh folder configured for it? @muru

Comment: @muru I added the `.ssh` for www-data in the `/var/www/`  as thats the apache root.But still I get the permission denied error over web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.In my case,I was missing the `authorized_keys` and the `known_hosts` files in my `www-data` users root folder.I added .ssh folder under `/var/www/.ssh`. I previously only moved the ssh key files hence I faced the issue for not able to connect to the git repository over http.